# Error in building Liferay 6.2 portlet in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, liferay-6, ivy

I am getting below error when trying to create a portlet in Eclipse Juno using liferay 6.2 EE. Can you please let me know what i am missing in this? I am new to Liferay 6.2

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\Working\Liferay 6.2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\portlets\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Working\Liferay 6.2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\build-common-plugins.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Working\Liferay 6.2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\build-common.xml:47: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Working\Liferay 6.2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\build-common-ivy.xml:34: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Working\Liferay 6.2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\build-common-ivy.xml:50: impossible to resolve dependencies:
    resolve failed - see output for details

Total time: 1 minute 1 second
```

Comment: This is forum mentions the solution http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/30228435  hope it helps you..

Comment: I am not able to download ivy-cache.zip. It shows error and i am not able access the alernate link also as I am in a secured network.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the following message, mentioned in the forum?

```
[ivy:resolve] Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

If so this means ivy is attempting to access an SSL protected URL (https) that is using an invalid certificate.

You must provide more detail (full stacktrace and applicable ivy code) in order to diagnose further.